# Plotly Dash: dcc.RadioItems vertical alignment

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I would like to align vertically all options of a `dash_core_components.RadioItems`.
According to the [dash documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/radioitems), the default behavior should include a vertical alignment of the `RadioItems` options. If you wanted to align the options horizontally, you would have to specify:

```
labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
```

On the contrary, as default behavior I get a horizontal alignment and I don't know what to specify as the `display` item to get a vertical alignment of the `RadioItems` options.
Here my attempt until now:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.RadioItems(id = 'input-radio-button',
                                      options = [dict(label = 'A', value = 'A'),
                                                 dict(label = 'B', value = 'B')],
                                      value = 'A'),
                       html.P(id = 'output-text')])


@app.callback(Output('output-text', 'children'),
              [Input('input-radio-button', 'value')])
def update_graph(value):
    return f'The selected value is {value}'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

What I get:

[image]

I would like to get a results like this (image manually edited):
[image]

I found [this reference](https://community.plotly.com/t/has-something-changed-with-radio-items-orientation/23492) where this problem is mentioned. There, it is proposed to solve it by referring to an external stylesheet. I would like, if possible, to avoid this turnaround and solve it by specifying the correct option within the definition of the `RadioItems` element.

Version info:

```
Python  3.7.0
dash    1.12.0
plotly  4.7.0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the `labelStyle={'display': 'block'}` property to `dcc.RadioItems()` in order to vertically align the different options, but I suggest that you follow the recommendation in the Dash Community Forum, which is to always link the Dash CSS file [`bWLwgP.css`](https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css).

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem is that I already use this stylesheet: `app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])`. Could I manage two different stylesheets?

Comment: Yes you can include multiple sylesheets, even though some properties may overwrite each other. For your case it seems to be OK, if I run your code above with `app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'])` the radio items options become automatically vertically aligned (i.e. without adding `labelStyle={'display': 'block'}`).

Comment: In recent version, local stylesheets can be placed in `assets/` directory and automatically loaded.